# FreeNAS too many errors on disk

Tags: zfs, truenas

One disk of my FreeNAS has failed, the zpool only contains a virtual machine.

When I call `zpool status -v`, I get:

```
root@freenas:/ # zpool status -v
  pool: freenas-boot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:02:08 with 0 errors on Fri Dec 28 03:47:08 2018
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    freenas-boot  ONLINE       0     0     0
      da0p2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: vol1
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:00:02 with 15 errors on Fri Dec 28 08:54:54 2018
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    vol1                                            DEGRADED     0     0   231
      mirror-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0   471
        gptid/ab2edc42-7b17-11e8-b061-7c8bca013f2c  ONLINE       0     0   491
        gptid/aba87353-7b17-11e8-b061-7c8bca013f2c  DEGRADED     0     0   471  too many errors

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        vol1/discoubuntu:<0x1>
```

If I replace the failing drive, the file will be readable again?.

Is there a way to recover that file?.

Answer (score 3):

This message means that the file is irrecoverably damaged. Changing the disk will not magically repair it.  Restore from your backup.

Comment: The checksum was wrong on both disks of the mirror. It's possible the system is having another hardware problem, such as defective RAM or not having ECC RAM.